# Invalid use of non-static data memeber in for loop iterating a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following code:

```
template
<typename T>
class NumberContainer{
    public:
        NumberContainer(std::initializer_list<T> contents):contents_(contents){};
        ~NumberContainer(){};
        template <typename U>
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const NumberContainer<U>& obj){
            for(auto it=contents_.begin(); it!=contents_.end(); ++it)
                out << *it << " ";
            return out;
        }
    private:
        std::vector<T> contents_;
};
```

When I try to compile it gcc complains about the for loop saying `invalid use of nonstatit data member contents_` . Is it because the size of the vector is not known at compile time? And how can I solve it to iterate over the vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The friend function is not a member, so there is no `this` to allow you to directly access non-static members. Instead, you access the members of the function argument, like `obj.contents_`.